# Automated app installs for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, mobile, sdk

**Is it possible to automate app installs for iOS and Android?** Appreciate the sand-boxing and/or permissions on iOS might prevent one app auto-installing another.

For example, much like this tool (https://ninite.com/pro) can do for desktop/Windows can iOS/Android perform similar functions?

The use case is this - I want to find a way to help users secure their devices much quicker by auto-installing apps like anti-virus (Android), Password Manager, VPNs etc. The user would in effect be given the options to choose what they want downloaded, the app would build this list and then download all in one go.

Comment: You can't do this from an app in iOS.  If a device is managed by an MDM solution then it can push apps to the device.  iOS includes a password manager and VPNs aren't necessarily more secure; it depends if you trust the VPN provider or not.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 - I suspected this was the case. PM and VPN were only examples, appreciate your points on those. This begs the question...would I have to pay for an established MDM (of which all the bells and whistles like device tracking I wouldn't need) or is it possible to develop a very basic MDM that meets only our basic needs of pushing apps to the device?

Comment: I guess you could develop your own MDM server that only pushed the management policies you wanted.  It also depends on who your target market is; consumers may not want to allow you to manage their device.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a basic MDM on Android using the **Android Management APIs**.
That will allow you to control app updates to Android devices.
You can also use [Esper](https://esper.io/signup) to automate Android app installs and updates, which is essentially free up to 100 devices.